# Spring REST , как сгенировать HttpClient

Tags: java, spring, rest, client

Имеется spring boot приложение с rest контроллерами , возможно ли как-то сгенерировать по контроллерам Http клиент ?

Comment: А чем он будет отличаться от обычного httpclient? Не совсем понятно, что вы пытаетесь сделать.

Comment: http client просто выполняет готовый запрос , мне же нужно сгенерировать классы сервисы , которые будут сами ходить по нужным урлам и возвращать ДТО.

Answer (score 1):

Это https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/multi/multi_spring-cloud-feign.html, http://www.baeldung.com/intro-to-feign может помочь.

```
@FeignClient("stores")
public interface StoreClient {
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/stores")
    List<Store> getStores();

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/stores/{storeId}", consumes = "application/json")
    Store update(@PathVariable("storeId") Long storeId, Store store);
}
```